# How to set separator of one section of tableView to clear

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, separator

I have four sections in my tableView, and I want only the last section to have a clear separator. I know how to do this for the whole tableView, but cannot find any solution for my question. The only solution that I have thought of is to create the cell as an image in Photoshop and set that image as the cell background. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this without having to use Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

In View didLoad

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

And

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 1)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        view.tag = 101;
        [cell addSubview:view];
    }


    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        [[cell viewWithTag:101] setHidden:YES];
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        [[cell viewWithTag:101] setHidden:NO];
    }
    return cell;
}
```